# All two-point correlations equal to $0$, three-point correlation not $0$?

Tags: pr.probability, ergodic-theory, markov-chains

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dotsc \in \{-1,1\}$ be a sequence. Suppose that, for all $j>0$ and all
$\epsilon, \epsilon'\in \{-1,1\}$, the proportion of $n\geq 1$ such that $(a_n,a_{n+j}) = (\epsilon,\epsilon')$ is $1/4$ (in the limit). I would like to see an example of such a sequence for which the average $S$ of $a_n a_{n+1} a_{n+2}$ is non-zero.

(... or doesn't exist; that would also be interesting.)

Reasons why this does not seem utterly trivial:

(a) We cannot have $S=1$ or $S=-1$; in fact, it's not too hard to show (using Cauchy-Schwarz) that $|S|\leq 1/\sqrt{2}$.

(b) Trying to produce such a sequence by a Markov chain where $a_{n+2}$ takes the value $1$ with probability $p_{(a_n,a_{n+1})}$ fails; that is, the only way in which the conditions are fulfilled (that is, all configurations $(a_n,a_{n+j})$ are equally likely) is if $p(a_n,a_{n+1}) = 1/2$ for every choice of $(a_n,a_{n+1})$. In other words, we would need a Markov chain of greater "depth".

Further, more open-ended question: what would be a "magic sauce" condition such that, if all configurations $(a_n,a_{n+j}) = (\epsilon,\epsilon')$ are equally likely for every $j$, and $\{a_n\}_n$ has "magic sauce", then the average of $a_n a_{n+1} a_{n+2}$ is zero?

Answer (score 9):

I think you could make such an example by choosing any normal sequence $S$ on the alphabet $\{0,1,2,3\}$, and then applying the letter-to-word substitution $\tau$ defined by $0 \mapsto +++$, $1 \mapsto +--$, $2 \mapsto -+-$, $3 \mapsto --+$. (I'm abbreviating $1$ by $+$ and $-1$ by $-$.)

The twofold independence comes from normality of $S$; you basically just check that for any $0 \leq i,j < 3$ (representing locations within the $3$-blocks in the image of $\tau$), that the $16$ values $(\tau(a))(i), (\tau(b))(j)$ for $a,b \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ contain all four possible pairs four times each.

The lack of independence for $x_n x_{n+1} x_{n+2}$ is because of the lack of independence in the words $\tau(a)$; for $n$ a multiple of $3$, this product is always equal to $+1$, and for $n$ a non-multiple of $3$, the product is uniformly distributed over $+1$ and $-1$ for similar reasons as the pairwise independence argument above. So the average of $x_n x_{n+1} x_{n+2}$ should be $1/3 \cdot 1 + 1/3 \cdot 1 + 1/3 \cdot -1 = 1/3$. (Obviously some details are omitted here...)

Comment: NIce!! One can check the steps without calculation by noting that, for a random word, the distributions of any pair of letters is independent uniform, and then noting that all the problems we have to check involve at most two letters from each word, hence have all letters independent uniform.

Comment: Yes, I think something like this is what I was clumsily trying to get at!

Answer (score 8):

$\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$Here is a suggestion, with some details missing. Let $\theta$ be an irrational number and set $r_n = \{ \theta n^2 \}$, where $\{ \alpha \}$ is the fractional part of $\alpha$. Then I claim that the pairs $(r_n, r_{n+j})$ are equidistributed in $(\RR/\ZZ)^2$, but $(r_n, r_{n+1}, r_{n+2})$ is not equidistributed in $(\RR/\ZZ)^{3}$.

**Proof of pairwise equidsitribution:** To see that $(r_n, r_{n+j})$ is $0$, we just need to check that the expected value of $\exp((2 \pi i) (a r_n + b r_{n+j})$ is nonzero for any $(a,b) \in \ZZ^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \}$. In other words, we need the expected values of $\exp((2 \pi i) \theta ((a+b) n^2 + 2bj n + b j^2))$ to be $0$. This follows from [Weyl's equidistribution theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128/how-do-you-prove-that-pn-xi-for-xi-irrational-and-p-a-polynomial-is-un), since it is impossible that $a+b=2b=0$ for $(a,b) \neq (0,0)$.
$\square$

**Proof of triple non-equidsitribution:** We have $(\theta (n+2)^2) - 2 \theta (n+1)^2 + \theta n^2 = 2 \theta$. So
$$r_{n+2} - 2 r_{n+1} + r_n = 2\theta \bmod \ZZ.$$
We also know that
$$-2 \leq r_{n+2} - 2 r_{n+1} + r_n \leq 2.$$
So $r_{n+2} - 2 r_{n+1} + r_n$ lies on $4$ hyperplanes through the cube $[0,1)^3$. $\square$

Now, choose any function $f : \RR/\ZZ \to \{ \pm 1 \}$ with average value $0$. Then $f(r_n)$ will have all pointwise correlations $0$, but there is no reason that the triple correlation should vanish.

It probably wouldn't be hard to explicitly show that the triple correlation doesn't vanish, for some well chosen $f$, but I'll stop here.

Comment: Nice. But might this in some sense be the only kind of example? How to detect it (see my comment on "magic sauce" above).

Comment: It's a good question, and I think that Tao and Gowers have thought about things like this, but I don't have the answer. Let's see if someone shows up who does.

Comment: Note that $f$ sending $[0,1/2)$ to $-1$ and $[1/2,1)$ to $+1$ doesn't work, since the distribution of triples is symmetric under negation and thus the triple correlation vanishes. But I agree that maybe another $f$ works.

Comment: We can allow $f$ to be valued in $[-1,1]$, instead of $\{-1,1\}$, by interpreting a value $a$ as a probability $\frac{a+1}{2}$ of $+1$ and $\frac{1-a}{2}$ of $-1$.  Then choosing $f (\theta/2 \pi)= c_1 \cos (\theta) + c_2 \cos(2\theta)$, the triple correlation is $c_1^2 c_2 /4$, and choosing small enough nonzero $\theta$ gives the desired example.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\{b_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables taking the values $\pm 1$ with probability $1/2$ each. Define $\{a_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ by
$a_n=b_{n-1} b_{n-2}$ if $\; n \equiv 0  \mod 3$ and  $a_n=b_n$ otherwise.
Then the  variables $a_n$ are pairwise independent. For example, if $\epsilon, \sigma \in {\pm1 }$ then $P(a_2=\epsilon,a_3=\sigma)=P(a_1=\sigma\epsilon, a_2=\sigma)=1/4$.

Thus, by the Law of large numbers, for all $j>0$ and all
$\epsilon, \sigma\in \{-1,1\}$, the limiting proportion of $n\geq 1$ such that $(a_n,a_{n+j}) = (\epsilon,\sigma)$ is $1/4$ with probability 1.
(Formally, to apply the LLN, consider for each integer $\ell \in [0,2j)$ the
limiting proportion of $k\geq 1$ such that $(a_{2kj+\ell},a_{2kj+\ell+j}) = (\epsilon,\sigma)$, then average over $\ell$.)
However, the asymptotic average   of $a_n a_{n+1} a_{n+2}$ is $1/3$ almost surely.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the argument given by @RonniePavlov.

Comment: Indeed. The underlying observation is that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent uniform elements of a finite (or compact) group $G$, then $X,Y, XY$ are three pairwise independent (but dependent) uniform variables in $G$.